# javafx 2 drag and drop object

Tags: javafx-2

I recently discovered JavaFX so I've decided to give it a try. I'm using JavaFX 2.2 beta for windows.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a drag and drop interface with Java Objects, a whole Scene with its child nodes. To be more specific, the user should be able to open up for example a log-in window and drag and drop this on the main application. The examples I've found are only bringing up drag and drop with Strings and images.

I found a good tutorial, but with strings. I can't figure out how to do this with a whole scene. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm

Can this be done?

Comment: I think i just came up with a solution, will post it later.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to go, although I'm not fully satisfied with it.

When the source receives a specific String in setOnDragDropped() the source creates a new object and deletes/closes the old one. The String is specifiFor the user it doesn't matter if it's the same scene or a new one.